# Is there a way to assign an application to always open on a specific space?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-spaces

Is there a way to assign an application to always open on a specific space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to **System Preferences -> Expose and Spaces**
- Drag your application into the list or click the **+** button to add it
- Choose which space you want them to open on